# how can I change lolipop stroke color in amchart library per value?

Tags: reactjs, amcharts, amcharts4

[image]

```
 // change stroke color per value
  series.adapter.add('stroke', function (stroke, target) {
    if (!target.dataItem) {
      return stroke;
    }

    var values = target.dataItem.values;

    return values.valueY.value < 100
      ? 'red'
      : values.valueY.value > 100
      ? 'yellow'
      : 'green';
  });
```

in the amchart v4 this function just return green stroke color , but I want return conditional stroke colors.

Answer (score 0):

You should set your adapter on `series.columns.template` instead of `series`.

```js
am4core.ready(function() {

  var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

  chart.data = [
    {
      category: "Category 1",
      value: 25
    },
    {
      category: "Category 2",
      value: 50
    },
    {
      category: "Category 3",
      value: 75
    },
    {
      category: "Category 4",
      value: 100
    },
    {
      category: "Category 5",
      value: 125
    },
    {
      category: "Category 6",
      value: 150
    },
    {
      category: "Category 7",
      value: 175
    }
  ];

  var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
  categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "category";
  categoryAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 15;
  categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0.5;
  categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.rotation = -90;
  categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.horizontalCenter = "left";
  categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.location = 0.5;
  categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.adapter.add("dx", function(dx, target) {
      return -target.maxRight / 2;
  });

  var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
  valueAxis.min = 0;
  valueAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 50;

  var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
  series.dataFields.categoryX = "category";
  series.dataFields.valueY = "value";
  series.columns.template.width = 0.01;
  
  var bullet = series.bullets.create(am4charts.CircleBullet);
  bullet.strokeWidth = 0;
  
  // The interesting part starts here!
  
  function colorize(strokeOrFill, item) {
    if (!item) {
      return strokeOrFill;
    }
    
    return item.values.valueY.value < 100
      ? "red"
      : item.values.valueY.value > 100
      ? "yellow"
      : "green";
  }
  
  series.columns.template.adapter.add("stroke", function(stroke, target) {
    return colorize(stroke, target.dataItem);
  });
  
  bullet.adapter.add("fill", function(fill, target) {
    return colorize(fill, target.dataItem);
  });

});
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>

<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```